# Disable window grouping in the Dock on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, window, ubuntu-dock

Is there any way in Ubuntu 18.04 that windows of the same application can be opened with each window having its own icon in the Dock, i.e. if you open Firefox twice that makes two separate Firefox icons in the Dock and not a single Firefox icon with little black triangle(s) indicating that there are multiple Firefox windows open at the same time?